# Export a hash from a module to a script

Tags: perl, module, exporter

refering back to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109672/how-to-make-a-hash-available-in-another-module), I'm strugglying with the way how to export datas from my module. One way is working but not the other one which I would like to implement.

The question is why the second method in the script is not working ?
(I did not h2xs the module as I guess this is for distributing only)

Perl 5.10/ Linux distro

**Module** my_common_declarations.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  
package my_common_declarations;  
use strict;  
use warnings;

use parent qw(Exporter);  
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(debugme);  

# local datas
my ( $tmp, $exec_mode, $DEBUGME );
my %debug_hash = ( true => 1, TRUE => 1, false => 0, FALSE => 0, tmp=>$tmp, exec=>$exec_mode, debugme=>$DEBUGME );

# exported hash
sub debugme {
return %debug_hash;
}
1;
```

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use my_common_declarations qw(debugme);  

# 1st Method: WORKS  
my %local_hash = &debugme;  
print "\n1st method:\nTRUE: ". $local_hash{true}. " ou : " . $local_hash{TRUE} , "\n";  

# 2nd Method: CAVEATS  
# error returned : "Global symbol "%debug_hash" requires explicit package name"  
print "2nd method \n " . $debug_hash{true};  

__END__
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to say `$local_hash{true}` instead of `$debug_hash{true}` near the end?

Comment: No, I was willing to get the hash ref from the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re returning not a hash but rather a copy of the hash.  All hashes passed into **or out of** a function get dehashed into a key-value pairlist.  Hence, a copy.

Return a reference to the hash instead:

```
 return \%debug_hash;
```

But this reveals your internals to the world outside.  Not a very clean thing to do.

You could also add `%debug_hash` to your `@EXPORT` list, but that’s an even dodgier thing to do. Please please please use a functional interface only, and you won’t regret it — and more importantly, neither shall anyone else. :)

Comment: Many thx. This reflects quite clearly my bad understanding of references, now better thx to your explanation.

Comment: I understand it's much much better to code a standalone packakge as a functional i,nterface but that's the only solution I found to "pack" "common" datas, used in many other scripts and/or packages.