# Empty a dynamically created array in a Perl Module

Tags: perl, cgi

Hi Guys need some help regarding modules and emptying dynamically created array in another module.

I have 1 perl file, and 2 perl modules ( i have created )

```
//file.pl

use ABC;
use XYZ;

for(qw/US UK China India France/)
{
   ABC::fetchData // This will create array varialbes
   XYZ::calculateYield 
    // This will use arrays dynamically created from fetchData
    // At this point, when i return I want a new copy of the array used in XYZ.pm's calculateYield function 
}
```

This is a an example of ABC.pm

```
//ABC.pm
package ABC;

our @mainArray;

sub fetchData
{
  // connect to database and fill up the @mainArray;
  @mainArray = qw/a b c d e f/;

}

1;
```

This is an example of XYZ.pm

```
//XYZ.pm
package XYZ;

sub calculateYield
{

  foreach my $eachelement ( @ABC::mainArray)
   {
       push @{$eachelement), "some_data_that_changes_every_time_from India, UK, US, France or China";
   }

}
```

Now, the problem lies here, I want to empty out the array "**@{$eachelement}**" after every call of **for(1..5)** , because the **$eachelement** stays the same in every count. Only the value of the data that is pushed into **push @{$eachelement)** in the XYZ module changes depending on the value ( US, UK, China, India, France).

Question for the group is, is there a way to empty out an array in a module whose name is dynamically created. As for example i want to clear out ***@{$eachelement}*** in the XYZ.pm after everytime the for loop is done.

Hope I have put it in a way that can be understood. If anyof you have a better solution or something else I can use,I am willing to do that. Ping me back if the question or any part of the code is not clear.

PS : I am not looking for a small error or typo, this is just a sample code. I just want to know how things can be done.

Thanks for the much anticipated help in advance.

Comment: Please provide code that at least compiles and runs under `use strictures;`, even if it doesn't do everything you want yet or produces the wrong results. By doing so, you will vastly increase your chances of having your question answered in a meaningful way. – When fixing the various syntax errors, the code still throws `Can't use string ("a") as an ARRAY ref…`, look into that first. – You should decouple access to member data in other modules as soon as practical, see code examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109672/how-to-make-a-hash-available-in-another-module/3110097#3110097

Comment: did you know the comment indicator in perl is `#` not `//`?

Answer (score -1):

I looked around and found a solution to this particular problem. I defined a global function

```
sub clear
{
       for my $ref (values %MSQL::) 
    {
        @{$ref} = ();
    }
}
```

Thanks Guys for the support.

@Patrick , this was not a TYPO error. Like I said I was looking for the logic.